# First time working with interactive plots in ggplotly, would like some feedback on my plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, plotly

This is my first time working with ggplot2/ggploty() and would like some feedback as to what I could do to make my plot better.

This is the code i've used:

```
 # interactive plot with ribbon
test <- ggplot(data = wide.data, aes(x = x, y = pred)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lwr, ymax = upr, fill = model), alpha = .5) + 
  geom_point(aes( group = model, fill = model)) + 
  labs(x = "Number of Games Played", y = "Total Number of Goals") + scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,70,5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,50,5))

ggplotly(test)
```

Local Hosts won't work so here is the short version, even though its not so short:

```
> dput(wide.data)
structure(list(x = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 
34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 
36L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 
38L, 38L), model = c("BLI", "BPL", "LG1", "LGA", "MLS", "SRA", 
"BLI", "BPL", "LG1", "LGA", "MLS", "SRA", "BLI", "BPL", "LG1", 
"LGA", "MLS", "SRA", "BLI", "BPL", "LG1", "LGA", "MLS", "SRA", 
"BLI", "BPL", "LG1", "LGA", "MLS", "SRA", "BLI", "BPL", "LG1", 
"LGA", "MLS", "SRA", "BLI", "BPL", "LG1", "LGA", "MLS", "SRA", 
"BLI", "BPL", "LG1", "LGA", "MLS", "SRA", "BLI", "BPL", "LG1", 
"LGA", "MLS", "SRA", "BLI", "BPL", "LG1", "LGA", "MLS", "SRA", 
"BLI", "BPL", "LG1", "LGA", "MLS", "SRA", "BLI", "BPL", "LG1", 
"LGA", "MLS", "SRA", "BLI", "BPL", "LG1", "LGA", "MLS", "SRA", 
"BLI", "BPL", "LG1", "LGA", "MLS", "SRA", "BLI", "BPL", "LG1", 
"LGA", "MLS", "SRA", "BLI", "BPL", "LG1", "LGA", "MLS", "SRA", 
"BLI", "BPL", "LG1", "LGA", "MLS", "SRA", "BLI", "BPL", "LG1", 
"LGA", "MLS", "SRA", "BLI", "BPL", "LG1", "LGA", "MLS", "SRA", 
"BLI", "BPL", "LG1", "LGA", "MLS", "SRA", "BLI", "BPL", "LG1", 
"LGA", "MLS", "SRA", "BLI", "BPL", "LG1", "LGA", "MLS", "SRA", 
"BLI", "BPL", "LG1", "LGA", "MLS", "SRA", "BLI", "BPL", "LG1", 
"LGA", "MLS", "SRA", "BLI", "BPL", "LG1", "LGA", "MLS", "SRA", 
"BLI", "BPL", "LG1", "LGA", "MLS", "SRA", "BLI", "BPL", "LG1", 
"LGA", "MLS", "SRA", "BLI", "BPL", "LG1", "LGA", "MLS", "SRA", 
"BLI", "BPL", "LG1", "LGA", "MLS", "SRA", "BLI", "BPL", "LG1", 
"LGA", "MLS", "SRA", "BLI", "BPL", "LG1", "LGA", "MLS", "SRA", 
"BLI", "BPL", "LG1", "LGA", "MLS", "SRA", "BLI", "BPL", "LG1", 
"LGA", "MLS", "SRA", "BLI", "BPL", "LG1", "LGA", "MLS", "SRA", 
"BLI", "BPL", "LG1", "LGA", "MLS", "SRA", "BLI", "BPL", "LG1", 
"LGA", "MLS", "SRA", "BLI", "BPL", "LG1", "LGA", "MLS", "SRA", 
"BLI", "BPL", "LG1", "LGA", "MLS", "SRA"), lwr = c(0.991908465191337, 
1.024356375271, 0.991908465191337, 0.713669169484484, 1.12586982342001, 
1.12084858138188, 2.06420487168374, 1.97777465268675, 2.06420487168374, 
1.62334863906913, 2.23910774286228, 2.21022346166219, 2.97388434126839, 
2.96968311787809, 3.11511279055919, 2.71272351934943, 3.36497756628229, 
3.11990293124683, 3.96579280645972, 3.96159158306943, 3.9773593493607, 
3.73707989462043, 4.47821548572456, 4.23314085068911, 4.95770127165106, 
4.91500986048518, 5.066734229641, 4.76143626989143, 5.60408530914457, 
5.18655912810486, 5.98205764692206, 5.7772564192867, 6.11764214851645, 
5.67111573947608, 6.72995513256457, 6.09623859768951, 6.9739661121134, 
6.49092558877118, 7.23849072989833, 6.4341005009485, 7.83280914918269, 
7.08814706288085, 7.92738438952915, 7.48283405396252, 8.10073728869984, 
7.38751877836426, 8.9356631658008, 8.08005552807218, 8.69036915100158, 
8.196503223447, 9.15164520757529, 8.43842669723971, 10.0615329892208, 
9.15235193456459, 9.68227761619292, 9.24741114232245, 10.0613246771599, 
9.43033516243104, 11.1747709086631, 10.0145984933661, 10.4951374013193, 
10.0103959037949, 11.0532331423513, 10.0959286392011, 12.2880088281053, 
11.0655064122415, 11.448555678735, 11.0023043689862, 12.0451416075426, 
10.8589134006735, 13.4163944903645, 12.0574148774329, 12.3582351483197, 
11.9119838385709, 13.0960495264181, 11.4335539927294, 14.5296324098068, 
13.1083227963083, 13.3825915235907, 12.8216633081555, 14.0057289960027, 
12.3869722701452, 15.6504809911887, 13.9705693551098, 14.0481850003607, 
13.4408352207955, 14.997637461194, 13.3788807353365, 16.7637189106309, 
15.0214772739853, 15.0990929192361, 14.2038199822679, 16.0699338676864, 
14.3707892005279, 17.8895887340509, 16.0937736804777, 16.0525111966519, 
15.1572382596836, 17.1593087479667, 15.3626976657192, 19.0104373154328, 
17.183148560758, 17.0059294740676, 16.1815946349546, 18.1127270253825, 
16.3546061309105, 20.1236752348751, 18.2340564796334, 18.0568373929431, 
17.0912741045393, 19.2259649448248, 17.1674659160369, 21.244523816257, 
19.2259649448248, 19.0487458581344, 17.8542588660117, 20.339202864267, 
17.9304506775093, 22.3729094785161, 20.1793832222405, 19.8616056432607, 
18.5679280354962, 21.3901107831425, 18.9548070527803, 23.4861473979584, 
21.230291141116, 20.8150239206765, 19.521346312912, 22.4410187020179, 
19.8644865223649, 24.5993853174007, 22.2221996063073, 21.7247033902612, 
20.5132547781033, 23.4919266208934, 20.9538614026453, 25.7252551408207, 
23.2141080714986, 22.7166118554525, 21.2762395395757, 24.4453448983091, 
21.9782177779162, 26.8461037222026, 24.0763546303002, 23.3822053322225, 
22.2681480047671, 25.3550243678938, 22.9701262431076, 27.9489577388207, 
24.9860340998848, 24.4065617074935, 23.2600564699584, 26.4059322867692, 
23.9620347082989, 29.062195658263, 26.0369420187603, 25.3162411770782, 
24.2844128452294, 27.3978407519606, 24.7748944934253, 30.1830442396449, 
27.1263168990406, 26.0792259385506, 25.2378311226451, 28.5186893333425, 
25.728312770841, 31.285898256263, 28.0359963686252, 27.0326442159663, 
25.8570030352851, 29.380935892144, 26.7202212360324, 32.3991361757052, 
28.8982429274267, 28.0245526811577, 26.5706722047696, 30.4532322986364, 
27.629900705617, 33.5250059991252, 30.011480846869, 29.0489090564287, 
27.4803516743542, 31.5426071789167, 28.295494182387, 34.6382439185675, 
31.0033893120603, 30.1212054629211, 28.4722601395456, 32.534515644108, 
29.3464021012625, 35.7514818380098, 31.9952977772517, 31.1131139281124, 
29.523168058421, 33.6238905243883, 30.0600712707469, 36.8773516614298, 
33.0462056961271, 32.1050223933037, 30.4328475280057, 34.6157989895797, 
30.6347118628029, 37.9982002428117, 34.167054277509, NA, 31.3425269975903, 
35.5254784591643, 31.5881301402187, 39.1240700662317, 35.2179621963844, 
NA, 32.2959452750061, 36.3877250179658, 32.58003860541, 40.2499398896517, 
36.2902586028768, NA, 33.1581918338076, 37.3796334831571, 33.3430233668824, 
41.3758097130717, 37.3625550093693, NA, 34.1825482090786, 38.4519298896496, 
34.3349318320738, 42.4890476325139, 38.4519298896496), pred = c(1.14244921317105, 
1.18853138677409, 1.14244921317105, 0.901144403312629, 1.56756991682395, 
1.50679152271014, 2.42879627669905, 2.28668514123042, 2.42879627669905, 
1.95672013877945, 3.01593956754501, 2.84502506662769, 3.48437201216587, 
3.42913435440147, 3.66526862143132, 3.294953682697, 4.58350948436895, 
3.90060080209451, 4.62682122533692, 4.57158356757252, 4.67991718843272, 
4.48348506947109, 6.03187913509002, 5.34897045281557, 5.76927043850797, 
5.66973732202884, 6.01815073235027, 5.67201645624518, 7.59944905191396, 
6.4471242072719, 6.95780182528206, 6.68438588903025, 7.25462307708254, 
6.72759219171201, 9.16701896873791, 7.50269994273873, 8.10025103845311, 
7.58553029234288, 8.76141459979268, 7.66508542555129, 10.559231901657, 
8.64514915590978, 9.19840479290944, 8.72797950551393, 9.77606316679409, 
8.76323918000761, 11.951444834576, 9.78759836908083, 10.1358980267487, 
9.62912390882656, 11.0125355115264, 9.99971152473988, 13.5190147514, 
11.0739454326088, 11.2783472399198, 10.8655962535588, 12.0681112469932, 
11.1421607379109, 14.967384402121, 12.0885939996102, 12.2536554815996, 
11.8030894873981, 13.2105604601642, 12.0083656408477, 16.4157540528421, 
13.3250663443425, 13.3518092360559, 12.9455387005692, 14.3530096733353, 
12.945858874687, 18.0465539392867, 14.4675155575135, 14.4073849715227, 
14.001114436036, 15.5894820180675, 13.7461963137094, 19.4949235900078, 
15.7039879022458, 15.5959163582968, 15.0566901715028, 16.6450577535344, 
14.8443500681658, 21.0017151127179, 16.7186364692472, 16.4621212612336, 
15.8893102611506, 17.7875069667054, 15.9867992813368, 22.450084763439, 
17.9551088139795, 17.6985936059659, 16.8268034949899, 19.0738540302334, 
17.1292484945079, 24.0176546802629, 19.2414558775075, 18.7967473604222, 
17.9249572494462, 20.412087574151, 18.2716977076789, 25.5244462029731, 
20.579689421425, 19.8949011148785, 19.1134886362203, 21.5102413286073, 
19.41414692085, 26.9728158536941, 21.8161617661573, 21.1313734596108, 
20.1690643716871, 22.9586109793284, 20.3894551625298, 28.4796073764043, 
22.9586109793284, 22.2738226727819, 21.1065576055264, 24.4069806300494, 
21.3269483963691, 30.1104072628489, 24.0567647337847, 23.2491309144617, 
22.007702008839, 25.6434529747817, 22.5154797831431, 31.55877691357, 
25.2932370785169, 24.347284668918, 23.1058557632954, 26.879925319514, 
23.57105551861, 33.007146564291, 26.435686291688, 25.4028604043848, 
24.2483049764664, 28.1163976642462, 24.9092890625275, 34.574716481115, 
27.5781355048591, 26.5453096175559, 25.1857982103057, 29.2145514187025, 
26.0978204493016, 36.0815080038251, 28.5927840718605, 27.4115145204927, 
26.3282474234767, 30.2701271541694, 27.2402696624727, 37.4737209367442, 
29.6483598073273, 28.6000459072668, 27.4706966366478, 31.5065994989016, 
28.3827188756437, 38.9220905874652, 30.8848321520595, 29.6556216427336, 
28.6592280234219, 32.6490487120727, 29.3580271173235, 40.4288821101754, 
32.2230656959771, 30.5931148765729, 29.7573817778782, 34.1558402347828, 
30.4561808717798, 41.8210950430944, 33.2786414314439, 31.6912686310292, 
30.590001867526, 35.1704888017842, 31.5986300849509, 43.2694646938155, 
34.2932899984453, 32.8337178442003, 31.4911462708386, 36.4568358653122, 
32.6542058204177, 44.8370346106394, 35.7416596491664, 34.0222492309743, 
32.5467220063055, 37.7950694092298, 33.5204107233545, 46.2854042613605, 
36.8841088623374, 35.3085962945023, 33.6891712194765, 38.9375186224008, 
34.7568830680868, 47.7337739120815, 38.0265580755085, 36.4510455076734, 
34.9256435642088, 40.2757521663184, 35.6580274713994, 49.3013438289055, 
39.2630304202408, 37.5934947208444, 35.9812192996756, 41.4182013794894, 
36.4583649104218, 50.8081353516156, 40.7698219429509, NA, 37.0367950351424, 
42.4737771149563, 37.5565186648782, 52.3757052684396, 42.0062942876832, 
NA, 38.1349487895988, 43.4884256819577, 38.6989678780492, 53.9432751852635, 
43.2926413512112, NA, 39.1495973566002, 44.6308748951287, 39.6364611118885, 
55.5108451020875, 44.5789884147392, NA, 40.3381287433743, 45.9172219586567, 
40.7789103250595, 56.9592147528085, 45.9172219586567), upr = c(1.29298996115076, 
1.35270639827718, 1.29298996115076, 1.08861963714077, 2.00927001022789, 
1.8927344640384, 2.79338768171436, 2.59559562977408, 2.79338768171436, 
2.29009163848977, 3.79277139222773, 3.47982667159319, 3.99485968306336, 
3.88858559092484, 4.21542445230345, 3.87718384604457, 5.80204140245562, 
4.68129867294219, 5.28784964421412, 5.18157555207561, 5.38247502750475, 
5.22989024432175, 7.58554278445547, 6.46480005494204, 6.58083960536488, 
6.4244647835725, 6.96956723505955, 6.58259664259894, 9.59481279468335, 
7.70768928643894, 7.93354600364207, 7.5915153587738, 8.39160400564863, 
7.78406864394794, 11.6040828049112, 8.90916128778794, 9.22653596479283, 
8.68013499591458, 10.284338469687, 8.89607035015407, 13.2856546541312, 
10.2021512489387, 10.4694251962897, 9.97312495706534, 11.4513890448883, 
10.138959581651, 14.9672265033512, 11.4951412100895, 11.5814269024959, 
11.0617445942061, 12.8734258154774, 11.5609963522401, 16.9764965135791, 
12.9955389306531, 12.8744168636466, 12.4837813647952, 14.0748978168264, 
12.8539863133908, 18.759997895579, 14.1625895058544, 14.0121735618799, 
13.5957830710013, 15.3678877779772, 13.9208026424944, 20.5434992775788, 
15.5846262764435, 15.2550627933768, 14.8887730321521, 16.6608777391279, 
15.0328043487006, 22.6767133882089, 16.8776162375942, 16.4565347947258, 
16.0902450335011, 18.082914509717, 16.0588386346895, 24.4602147702088, 
18.2996530081833, 17.809241193003, 17.2917170348501, 19.284386511066, 
17.3017278661863, 26.3529492342472, 19.4667035833846, 18.8760575221066, 
18.3377853015058, 20.5773764722168, 18.5947178273371, 28.136450616247, 
20.8887403539737, 20.2980942926957, 19.4497870077119, 22.0777741927804, 
19.8877077884879, 30.1457206264749, 22.3891380745373, 21.5409835241926, 
20.6926762392088, 23.6648664003352, 21.1806977496386, 32.0384550905133, 
23.9762302820921, 22.7838727556895, 22.045382637486, 24.9077556318321, 
22.4736877107894, 33.8219564725131, 25.3982670526812, 24.2059095262785, 
23.246854638835, 26.6912570138319, 23.6114444090227, 35.7146909365515, 
26.6912570138319, 25.4988994874293, 24.3588563450411, 28.4747583958318, 
24.7234461152288, 37.8479050471816, 27.9341462453288, 26.6366561856626, 
25.4474759821819, 29.8967951664209, 26.076152513506, 39.6314064291815, 
29.3561830159179, 27.8795454171595, 26.6903652136788, 31.31883193701, 
27.277624514855, 41.4149078111813, 30.6491729770687, 29.0810174185085, 
27.9833551748295, 32.740868707599, 28.8647167224098, 43.4241778214092, 
31.9421629382194, 30.3740073796592, 29.0953568810357, 33.9837579390959, 
30.217423120687, 45.3169122854476, 33.1092135134207, 31.4408237087628, 
30.3883468421864, 35.1852299404449, 31.5104130818377, 46.9984841346676, 
34.3106855147697, 32.79353010704, 31.6813368033372, 36.607266711034, 
32.8034030429885, 48.7819855166675, 35.7327222853588, 33.995002108389, 
33.0340432016144, 37.9002566721848, 33.9411597412217, 50.6747199807059, 
37.3198144929136, 35.1070038145952, 34.2769324331113, 39.7929911362232, 
35.1840489727186, 52.3562918299259, 38.5212864942626, 36.349893046092, 
35.3230006997669, 40.9600417114245, 36.4770389338694, 54.1397932119257, 
39.6883370694639, 37.6428830072428, 36.4116203369077, 42.4604394319881, 
37.6785109352184, 56.1490632221536, 41.4718384514638, 38.99558940552, 
37.6130923382567, 44.0475316395429, 38.745327264322, 57.9325646041534, 
42.7648284126145, 40.4959871260836, 38.9060822994075, 45.3405216006936, 
40.1673640349111, 59.7160659861533, 44.0578183737653, 41.7889770872344, 
40.3281190699966, 46.9276138082484, 41.2559836720519, 61.7253359963812, 
45.4798551443544, 43.0819670483851, 41.5295910713456, 48.2206037693992, 
42.2820179580408, 63.6180704604196, 47.3725896083928, NA, 42.7310630726946, 
49.4220757707482, 43.5249071895377, 65.6273404706475, 48.7946263789819, 
NA, 43.9739523041915, 50.5891263459495, 44.8178971506884, 67.6366104808753, 
50.2950240995455, NA, 45.1410028793928, 51.8821163071003, 45.9298988568945, 
69.6458804911032, 51.7954218201091, NA, 46.4937092776699, 53.3825140276639, 
47.2228888180453, 71.4293818731031, 53.3825140276639)), .Names = c("x", 
"model", "lwr", "pred", "upr"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
228L))
```

Also, I had specific questions as well:

- Since a few of my ribbons are overlapping, is there a way to force the plot to open with only 2 ribbons showing?
- Is there a way to manually override the values listed in the Legend. I know they are driven by what is listed in the data frame `wide.data` but I wonder if there is a way to input my own text there.

Comment: If you provide a data sample using `dput(wide.data)` (a small version of it to reproduce the issue), we will be able to plot it locally.  You shouldn't need to provide a link to a plot for the code you have.

Comment: @steveb done. Still pretty large but that should help

Comment: The plots for `ggplot` and `plotly` are pretty much the same (that is not always the case as the axes can be clipped on a plotly plot).  It seems like your question is mainly focused around the `ggplot` part based on your questions.  Some clarifications are needed (for me at least), are you saying you want only a subset of lines to have ribbons ?  What exactly do you want in the legend.

Comment: For your first question, you can click on the legend to show/hide plot lines/ribbons when you use the plot from `ggplotly(test)`.

Comment: So, as you can see in the ggplotly plot, the legend lists BLI, BPL etc but instead i'd rather have Bundesliga, Premier League etc. 

Would you suggest I work solely with ggplot or would it be helpful for me to work with plotly for some aspects?

Comment: See my previous comment about clicking on the legend items in a `plotly` plot.

Comment: Ok, so say I wanted to embed this plot into a blog post, is there a way to ensure that the viewer will see just two variables of my choosing rather than all 5.

Comment: You should include that in your question or ask a different question.  That being said, I don't know the answer to adding it to a blog post.  Can you just try it ?

Comment: Will do, other than that. Do you have any feedback on the plot? Anything you would change?

Comment: It depends on what you want to use it for and what you are trying to show.  What is the goal for using the data.  The "right" way to visualize will likely depend on what questions you want to answer.  This may not be the answer you want.  This may result in a number of StackOverfow/Cross Validated/StackExchange questions.  The ability to use `plotly` to hide/show data is useful at times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can set plot to open with some ribbons hidden if you build the plot directly using `plot_ly()` (instead of ggplot) by using `visible="legendonly"`.
2. You can set the names of each trace as they appear in the legend using `name=`.

A minimal example:

```
my.data = data.frame(x=1:40, y=1:40)
plot_ly(my.data, x=x, y=y, mode="markers", name="foo") %>%
  add_trace(type="area", x=c(x,rev(x)), y= c(y+10, rev(y)-10), 
            fill = "toself", visible="legendonly", name="bar")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have some follow up questions. So, with my plot, the ribbons and prediction lines are tied together i.e. the legend buttons should hide a specific prediction line along with its associated ribbon. It seems like plot_ly plots everything separately.